# Java method restriction for different instance of same class

Tags: java

Suppose you have user class which has two method like `methoda` and `methodb`. We create two instance of this class `a` and `b`. Now I want to update my code that `methoda` should be visible to only instance `a` and `methodb` should be visible to instance `b`. I did not get how we can achieve this in Java.

Comment: what about instance c and d and so on ??? i mean method should be visible or not ??

Answer (score 1):

No, method visibility is always based on *types*, not individual instances. It sounds like perhaps you should actually have two subclasses, one with `methodA` and one with `methodB`; you can then create instances of the appropriate subclass.

Answer (score 1):

You could do it like this:

```
public interface InterfaceA { void methodA(); }

public interface InterfaceB { void methodB(); }

public class User implements InterfaceA, InterfaceB {

public void methodA() { System.out.println("method A"); }

public void methodB() { System.out.println("method B"); }

}
```

// some where else

```
InterfaceA a = new User();
InterfaceB b = new User();
```

Now, `a` "sees" only `methodA()` and `b` "sees" only `methodB()`

I think there is no other way to do this.

Comment: That's indeed the way to go. Using interfaces to restrict the actions of a reference is maybe the most important design pattern for safe design.

Answer (score 0):

If both `a` and `b` are instances of the same class, you can't do that. Both instances have the same methods (aka behaviour in OOP speak).

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Polymorphism and *hage* answers your question.

To understand what happens during polymorphism read on.

1. The compiler looks at the declared type of the object and the method name. Let’s say 
   we call `x.fun(param)`, and the implicit parameter x is declared to be an object of class C.

Note that there may be multiple methods, all with the same name, fun, but with different 
parameter types. For example, there may be a method f(int) and a method f(String).
The compiler enumerates all methods called fun in the class C and all public/protected methods called fun in the superclasses of C.

Now the compiler knows all possible candidates for the method to be called.

1. Next, the compiler determines the types of the parameters that are supplied in the 
   method call. If among all the methods called fun there is a unique method whose 
   parameter types are a best match for the supplied parameters, then that method is 
   chosen to be called. This process is called **overloading resolution**.
2. If the method is private, static, final, or a constructor, then the compiler knows exactly which method to call. Compiler then uses static binding.
   Else if the method to be called depends on the actual type of implicit parameter, Compiler uses dynamic binding.
3. When the program runs and uses dynamic binding to call a method, *then the virtual 
   machine must call the version of the method that is appropriate for the actual type of 
   the object to which  x refers*.

Let’s say the actual type is D, a subclass of C. If the class D defines a method fun(String), that method is called. 
If not, D’s superclass is searched for a method  fun(String), and so on. 
It would be time consuming to carry out this search every time a method is called. 
Therefore, the virtual machine pre-computes for each class a method table that lists all 
method signatures and the actual methods to be called. When a method is actually 
called, the virtual machine simply makes a **table lookup**.